# How do I translate this CMake file to QMake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, makefile, qmake

[Minimal example .zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIYX2PTQDCQ3EThHaXHZ1sFJC3JNjqH-/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to use [SoLoud](https://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/) in my Qt project.

I managed to successfully compile & use it with this cmake file:

```cmake
file(GLOB_RECURSE AUDIOSOURCE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SoLoud/src/audiosource/*.c*)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CORE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SoLoud/src/core/*.c*)
file(GLOB_RECURSE FILTER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SoLoud/src/filter/*.c*)

add_compile_definitions(WITH_MINIAUDIO)

set(SOLOUD_SRCS 
    SoLoud/src/backend/miniaudio/soloud_miniaudio.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SoLoud/src/c_api/soloud_c.cpp
    ${AUDIOSOURCE}
    ${CORE}
    ${FILTER}
)

add_executable(output main.cpp ${SOLOUD_SRCS})
target_include_directories(output PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SoLoud/include)
```

My main project is built with Qmake. So I'm trying to translate it...

```qmake
INCLUDEPATH += SoLoud/include

DEFINES += "WITH_MINIAUDIO=\"\""

SOURCES += SoLoud/src/backend/miniaudio/soloud_miniaudio.cpp \
           SoLoud/src/c_api/soloud_c.cpp \
           $$files("SoLoud/src/audiosource/*.c*", true) \
           $$files("SoLoud/src/core/*.c*", true) \
           $$files("SoLoud/src/filter/*.c*", true)

HEADERS += $$files("SoLoud/include/*.h", true) \
```

This produces a wall of errors:
https://pastebin.com/pUQuysEr

[image: errors]

Why?

BTW: i'm aware that recursive search of *.c* files is bad practice. However, that's what library's authors recommend and I gave up trying to find every single .cpp i need (there were MANY).

Comment: Please show a [mre] with the full error messages as text from the compiler output not a partial screenshot of the error list

Comment: @AlanBirtles Updated the image. [Here's a tiniest project possible](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIYX2PTQDCQ3EThHaXHZ1sFJC3JNjqH-/view?usp=sharing).
Import it to Qt creator, compile, and you should see errors.

Comment: You're getting linking errors. It can't find stb_vorbis_xxx stuff. Is that a library that is needed to be linked in? Or are those functions defined in the source library you are trying to build?

Comment: @JarMan This is inside SoLoud, the only external library in this project.